# SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern. D3 querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, d3.js

I am modifying this http://bl.ocks.org/slattery/52970ba87b5ad6f914804a19df639e3a

However, I need to node names to contain special character like `(`, `.`, `+`, or `#`
And this cause syntax error

I have tried add `\` before the special character however it cause the code not to run (null).

As per d3.v3.min.js, the last line below, throw error due to unmatching string pattern

```
 var So = /[\\\^\$\*\+\?\|\[\]\(\)\.\{\}]/g,
        ko = {}.__proto__ ? function(n, t) {
            n.__proto__ = t
        } : function(n, t) {
            for (var e in t)
                n[e] = t[e]
        },
        No = function(n, t) {
            return t.querySelector(n)
```

Is there a way to get around this? Or special character is a hard no for node naming..

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by 'node name'? The `id` attribute?

Comment: If you mean the title text of a node, just store it in an attribute value (not key) `{ id: ..., title: '...' }` and pass to `<text>` element:  `append('text').text(d => d.title)`

Comment: hi @MichaelRovinsky thank you for your comment. You are right, since the source of this issue is the key containing the special character. In that case, I will try to separate the key and the title, will keep u updated after I changed the code.

Comment: Hello @MichaelRovinsky, your solution works, thank you!